# Where to ask questions about non-linear video edit software?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Non-linear video edit soft is like Final Cut, Premiere, Aftereffects, Avid...

I have many questions about NLE software and such.

Is there an appropriate site for these in the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 3):

[Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) is the right site for those questions.  There are questions about [NLE](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=nle), [Final Cut](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=final%20cut), [Premiere](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premiere), [Aftereffects](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-effects), and [Avid](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=avid) on that site.